# "Valet parking " or "parking valet"

Tags: phrase-meaning

Which one is the correct form?

> "parking valet" or  "valet parking"

"Valet parking" is commonly used, but it seems that "parking valet" is also correct!

What's the grammatical explanation of these two correct forms of the phrase?

Comment: Did you look up these phrases in a dictionary?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The "parking valet" is the **person** who parks your car.
The "valet parking" is the **facility** that is offered.

If those phrases are part of an advertisement, they effectively mean the same thing, respectively

> We have a valet who will park your car.
>   We offer a car parking service.

Both your phrases consist of two nouns, and in each case the second word is the actual noun, while the first word is a [noun adjunct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_adjunct). This is a noun used like an adjective.

Comment: I would say that valet parking is the **service** being offered. The facility is a parking lot.

Comment: There is the further difference that "parking" is a mass noun, while "valet" is a count noun. Because of this, "parking valet" takes a determiner when used in the singular, while "valet parking" does not (in "a car parking service", "parking" is used as a noun adjunct; the main noun is "service", which is countable, and so "car parking service" takes the determiner "a").

Comment: @Acccumulation TL;DR "valet parking", "**a** parking valet".

Comment: @Barmar Look at no. 2 https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/facility

Comment: @Acccumulation you would not see a sign saying "a parking valet".

Comment: @WeatherVane "a parking valet" is a sentence fragment. *In a complete sentence*, "a parking valet" is the correct form. The rules for determiners don't apply to signs that merely label something. For instance, you can have a sign that just says "exit", rather than "an exit", even though "exit" is a countable noun that would require a determiner if it were used in a sentence.

Comment: @Acccumulation I think you should post your own answer.